# Distribution of combination of events with different distributions themselves

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, binomial-distribution, mixture-distribution

I am asked to find the PMF of $X$, for the following definition of $X$:

"There are two coins, one with probability $p_1$ of Heads and the other with probability $p_2$ of Heads. One of the coins is randomly chosen (with equal probabilities for the two coins). It is then flipped $n \geq 2$ times. Let $X$ be the number of times it lands Heads."

My intuition is that to choose the coin at random, there is first a Bernoulli distribution $Y \sim \operatorname{Bern} \left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)$, which has a simple PMF, namely $P(Y=1)=P(Y=0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then once the coin is chosen there is some binomial distribution $X \sim \operatorname{Bin} \left({n},p_i\right)$ where the PMF is $P_i(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p_i^k(1-p_i)^{n-k}$ for $i=1,2$.

I am confused as to how to combine these two distributions/PMFs together into one. I am also wondering what the distribution of $X$ would be if $p_1=p_2$; would it just be another binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1):

meow234.  The basic tools that we have for thinking about multiple random variables together are the **joing distributions** and **conditional distributions**.  When we want to go from thinking about multiple variables at once to fewer variables we need to **marginalize** to obtain **marginal distributions**.

So as you point out in your question we have $Y \sim \mathcal{Ber}(0.5)$.  (I'm going to use $p_0, p_1$ for ease of notation).  Then given $Y$ we know how to draw $X$, so we have a conditional distribution, $X|Y \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n, p_{Y})$.

We can then compute the PMF for the joint distribution of $X,Y$ by taking the product:

$$
P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x|Y=y)\cdot P(Y=y).
$$

At the end of the day, what we're interested in though is $P(X)$.  This requires that we **marginalize** the joint distribution by summing over all (both) possible values of $Y$.

$$
P(X=x) = P(X=x|Y=0)\cdot P(Y=0) + P(X=x|Y=1)\cdot P(Y=1).
$$

Why don't you see how far that gets you, and let me know if you have any questions by commenting on this answer.